# What's the difference between a variable in the EEPROM and RAM?

Tags: ram, rom

In javacard, what data is stored in the epprom? what data is stored in ram?

Answer (score 2):

One of the most direct methods: when we develop javacard applets, we will apply for memory for variables. The variable created by new() function will be stored in EEPROM, such as

```
byte[] tempBuffer; 
tempBuffer  = new byte[32];
```

Via JCSystem. MakeTransientByteArray () function will be stored in RAM, such as

```
byte[] tempBuffer;
tempBuffer = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)256, CSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT); // using either JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET or JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT
```

Comment: Is that true for any invocation of `new`? What about local variables (declared within the body of a method)? Are they also created in the EEPROM memory?

Answer (score 1):

Data stored in EEPROM will not be erased even after you remove the power supply to the card. Writing and reading from EEPROM is slower compared to RAM. Also, the number of possible EEPROM writes that you can perform is limited and reaching this limit might cause the card to be not useable anymore. This is called EEPROM wearing. So use EEPROM only if absolutely needed.

Data stored in RAM will be cleared (all bits set to 0) either when removing the power supply, or by deselecting the applet. This is usally used for temporary data which you can afford to lose after the card loses power. Unlike EEPROM, there is no limit on the number of RAM writes you can perform.